# input change detection not working while using a mask

Tags: jquery

I have a text field, I detect the changes with jQuery, then I de/activate a button if the value > 1000 (it's supposed to contain a price).
It's working fine.

Now I want to apply a mask on my input to format the value and restrict the characters like that :
99 999 999,99

the mask is working but then, the changes detection doesn't work anymore...

I'm using autoNumeric for my mask :
https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric

I've created 2 examples with jsfiddle :

- https://jsfiddle.net/dv75y8h6/ => working detection
- https://jsfiddle.net/pj368dc3/ => non working detection but working
  mask

Here is my javascript code :

```
    function activeInvoice(priceField) {
        console.log(priceField.val());
        var val = (priceField.val() >= 1000);
        $('#invoice_file').prop('disabled', !val);
        $('#invoice_file').prop('required', val);
    }

    $(function () {
        $('#price').autoNumeric("init", {
            aSep: ' ',
            aDec: ','
        });

        var priceField = $('#price');
        activeInvoice(priceField);

        $(document).on('input', '#price', function () {
            activeInvoice($(this));
        });
    });
```

I would like to have both working, of course !

Thanks

Comment: For info, autoNumeric not sending `input` nor `change` events was a bug that got [fixed](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric/issues/292). You can now use the mask transparently without it interfering with the default events (almost ;p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```js
        function activeInvoice(priceField) {            
            var priceField_value = priceField.val().replace(/ +/g, '');                
            var val = (parseInt(priceField_value) >= 1000);
            $('#invoice_file').prop('disabled', !val);
            $('#invoice_file').prop('required', val);
        }

        $(function () {
            $('#price').autoNumeric("init", {
                aSep: ' ',
                aDec: ','
            });
            
            var priceField = $('#price');
            activeInvoice(priceField);
            
           $(document).on('keyup', '#price', function () { activeInvoice($(this)); });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autonumeric/1.9.46/autoNumeric.js"></script>

<input id="price" type="text" />
<input id="invoice_file" type="button" value="test" />
```

Comment: Yes, it's almost there, thank you, I think I need to do something about the coma, if I had a decimal value in your example, it doesn't work.
Plus I need to check the keyup event like that $(document).on('keyup', '#price', function () {
                activeInvoice($(this));
            });
Since my field is dynamically loaded

Comment: To handle comma, update this code: var priceField_value = priceField.val().replace(/[, ]+/g, '');

Comment: Well if I do that, 10,00 will be converted to 1000 wich is not expected :p
If I use your first suggestion then do var val = (parseInt(priceField_value) >= 1000); it works fine, you can edit, then I'll accept your answer ;) Thank you !

Comment: Updated solution with first suggestion

Comment: Then var val = (parseInt(priceField.val()) >= 1000); on the 3rd line ;)

Comment: Added parseInt also for variable 'val'